# Scraping Data from Table with Multiple Pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-extraction

I am trying to scrape data from AGMARKNET website. The tables are split into 11 pages but all of the pages use the same url. I am very new to webscraping (or python in general), but AGMARKNET does not have a public API so scraping the page seems to be my only option. I am currently using BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML code and I am able to scrape the initial table, but that only contains the first 500 data points, but I want the entire 11 page data. I am stuck and frustrated. Link and my current code are below. Any direction would be helpful, thank you .
@αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη
https://agmarknet.gov.in/SearchCmmMkt.aspx?Tx_Commodity=17&Tx_State=JK&Tx_District=0&Tx_Market=0&DateFrom=01-Oct-2004&DateTo=18-Oct-2022&Fr_Date=01-Oct-2004&To_Date=18-Oct-2022&Tx_Trend=2&Tx_CommodityHead=Apple&Tx_StateHead=Jammu+and+Kashmir&Tx_DistrictHead=--Select--&Tx_MarketHead=--Select--

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://agmarknet.gov.in/SearchCmmMkt.aspx?Tx_Commodity=17&Tx_State=JK&Tx_District=0&Tx_Market=0&DateFrom=01-Oct-2004&DateTo=18-Oct-2022&Fr_Date=01-Oct-2004&To_Date=18-Oct-2022&Tx_Trend=2&Tx_CommodityHead=Apple&Tx_StateHead=Jammu+and+Kashmir&Tx_DistrictHead=--Select--&Tx_MarketHead=--Select--'

response = requests.get(url)

# Use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML code
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# changes stat_table from ResultSet to a Tag
stat_table = stat_table[0]

# Convert html table to list
rows = []
for tr in stat_table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    cells = []
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    if len(tds) == 0:
        ths = tr.find_all('th')
        for th in ths:
            cells.append(th.text.strip())
    else:
        for td in tds:
            cells.append(td.text.strip())
    rows.append(cells)

# convert table to df
table = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Comment: Maybe some server issues: I get `Server error please try again later.` when I try to go to page 2.

Comment: I am getting the same error @BarrythePlatipus

Comment: Your help is needed @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη

Answer (score 0):

The website you linked to seems to be using JavaScript to navigate to the next page. The `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` libraries are only for parsing static HTML pages, so they can't run JavaScript.

Instead of using them, you should try something like Selenium that actually simulates a full browser environment (including HTML, CSS, etc.). In fact, Selenium can even open a full browser window so you can see it in action as it navigates!

Here is a quick sample code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
# If you prefer Chrome to Firefox, there is a driver available
# for that as well

# Set the URL
url = 'https://agmarknet.gov.in/SearchCmmMkt.aspx?Tx_Commodity=17&Tx_State=JK&Tx_District=0&Tx_Market=0&DateFrom=01-Oct-2004&DateTo=18-Oct-2022&Fr_Date=01-Oct-2004&To_Date=18-Oct-2022&Tx_Trend=2&Tx_CommodityHead=Apple&Tx_StateHead=Jammu+and+Kashmir&Tx_DistrictHead=--Select--&Tx_MarketHead=--Select--'

# Start the browser
opts = Options()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
driver.get(url)
```

Now you can use functions like `driver.find_element(...)` and `driver.find_elements(...)` to extract the data you want from this page, the same way you did with BeautifulSoup.

For your given link, the page number navigators seem to be running a function of the form,

```js
__doPostBack('ctl00$cphBody$GridViewBoth','Page$2')
```

...replacing `Page$2` with `Page$3`, `Page$4`, etc. depending on which page you want. So you can use Selenium to run that JavaScript function when you're ready to navigate.

```py
driver.execute_script("__doPostBack('ctl00$cphBody$GridViewBoth','Page$2')")
```

A more generic solution is to just select which button you want and then run that button's `click()` function. General example (not necessarily for the current website):

```py
btn = driver.find_element('id', 'next-button')
btn.click()
```

A final note: after the button is clicked, you might want to `time.sleep(...)` for a little while to make sure the page is fully loaded before you start processing the next set of data.